# Is there a function to give options for input? I am running Python3, I get a ValueError when I use the $ in my input. This is my first Python script

Tags: python

```
bill = int(float(input("How much is your Bill? ")))
tip = int(input("Pick one of the following tip percentage amounts 15%, 18%, or 20%? "))
actual_tip = tip * bill / 100
total = actual_tip + bill

print(f"Your bill is ${bill:.2f} and your tip is ${actual_tip:.2f}, so your total bill including tip will be ${total:.2f}.")



PS C:\Users\PJ\Desktop\Python> python test2.py 
How much is your Bill? $10.00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    bill = int(float(input("How much is your Bill? ")))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$10.00'
```

when I use 10.00 or 10 it works but if I add $, I get the error ValueError

Comment: Because you can't convert `$` to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input `$` into it, program couldn't proceed that into a `float` and give an error.

```
inp = input("How much is your Bill? ")
if '$' in inp:
 inp = inp.strip('$')
bill = int(float(inp))
```

try solution above.

Comment: Strings are *immutable*. You need to assign the result of `strip` to some variable.

Comment: In Python 3, all input is taken as a string. The program is perfectly happy accepting an input of 10, or 10.0, or $10.00, or even "Please charge ten dollars to my credit card." and the program will accept all of these **as strings**. But before you can convert the input to a number, you must make sure that all non-digit characters have been removed or otherwise handles. Only then can you do the math to calculate a tip. This means removing the "$" from the string as other responders have shown you how to do.

Comment: Asocia is correct, but needs some explaination. Data types in Python are either mutable (as with lists) or immutable (as with strings.) 'Mutable' means it can be changed. 'Immutable' means it can not be changed. You can't change a string because it is immutable; but you CAN create an entirely NEW string and then reassign the old variable name to that new string. 
>> mystring = "hello" creates a string in memory and assigns it to the variable name mystring. 

But >> mystring = mystring + " world!", does not actually added anything to the original string. (It just looks like it does.)

Comment: Rather what happens is that an entirely NEW string is created by that line and the variable name is reassigned from the old string to the new.
 
This is why you must use inp = inp.strip('$') rather than just int.strip('$'). The second form create a string in memory, but NOTHING points to it, so it is useless and lost. (A mutable data type, by contrast, COULD be changed.) The line inp = inp.strip('$') creates a new string and then assigns that string to the variable name inp. Many of the quirks of Python start to make sense once you understand why they work as they do. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = "Your bill is {} and your tip is {}, so your total bill including tip will be {}.".format(bill,actual_tip,total)
print(string)
```